# Using same component twice in a component not working

Tags: reactjs

I trying to user `react-dates` in a component. It works fine for a single instance but not for multiple instances. As shown below:

WORKS (Shows a single date-range input, and shows calendar on click):

```
<DateRangePicker
    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })}
    />
```

DOES NOT WORK (Shows two date-range inputs, but won't show calendar on click):

```
<DateRangePicker
    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })}
    />

<DateRangePicker
    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })}
    />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try adding different focusedInput for start date and end date

Comment: It worked. But how? I added a new state `focusedInput2` in state and used it in 2nd instance instead of `focusedInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the DateRangePicker component are listening to same focusedInput in the state.
Date DateRangePicker has to have its own focusedInput in the this.state.
`focusedInput` and `focusedInput2`, then DateRangePicker can open the right calendar.